# can't get saltstack to work with influxdb module

Tags: saltstack

please bear with me; new to salt. i just want to get influxdb deployed and configured automagically with saltstack. i have:

```
$ cat /srv/salt/influx.sls
influxdb:
  pkg.installed:
    - sources:
      - influxdb: salt://influx/influxdb-0.8.8-1.x86_64.rpm
  service.running:
    - require:
      - pkg: influxdb
```

and doing a highstate works to get the thing installed.

however, i'm completely at a loss of how to configure influx from salt:

```
$ sudo salt hosta influxdb.db_create test
hosta:
    'influxdb.db_create' is not available.
```

can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

i was missing the pip module `influxdb`: add to salt state file:

```
python-pip:
  pkg.installed

influxdb-python:
  pip.installed:
    - name: influxdb
    - require:
       - pkg: python-pip

influxdb:
  pkg.installed:
    - sources:
      - influxdb: salt://influxdb/influxdb-0.8.8-1.x86_64.rpm
  service.running:
    - require:
      - pkg: influxdb
    - watch:
      - file: /opt/influxdb/current/config.toml
  module.run:
    - name: influxdb.db_create
    - m_name: test_db
```